# How can I get up to speed about Perl's latest object-oriented capabilities?

Tags: perl, oop

I have not done Perl for about 8 years and now I'm going into project that's heavily utilizing object-oriented Perl so I need to resharpen my Perl skills and do it quickly. During these past years I mainly did all sorts of Java development and some PHP. I'm very good at OO and I'm not a novice programmer by any remote extent.

So here comes the question: what are the best resources/sites/practices/ways/books you guys can recommend to pick up on my rusty Perl skills and learn Perl "the new way"? Your suggestions will be much appreciated.

P.S. I did researched some previous answers. I want to emphasize that I'm not looking for novice book/resource (syntax, core principals, etc) but specifically ones that cover OOP capabilities that weren't there when I was programming in Perl (or I may overlooked it at that time)

P.P.S. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions and tips. After some consideration I went with @MBO answer since it's first mentioning Moose which I really like so far.

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984868/is-my-book-too-old-to-learn-from-perl/984909#984909

Comment: Actually it refers to the book I have very little interest in. I don't need general syntax, I need OOP part of the language

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't write Perl code at this time (currently I work in other languages), but I read from time to time this site: http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/. Also check [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-0.94/lib/Moose.pm) for new way of defining objects in Perl

Comment: Moose is the leading OO framework in Perl

Comment: I'll second both the Modern Perl blog and Moose; check out Catalyzed for a quick Moose intro: http://www.catalyzed.org/2009/06/a-gentle-introduction-to-moose.html

Comment: why downvote? Should I copy answer from link posted in comment by [mercator](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23263/mercator)? Or I answered wrong to question?

Comment: I can't imagine that someone would downvote this answer (so I upvoted it) rather than trying to pull his own answer up. In fact - based on my question and timing (this one is first that mentions Moose) I'm considering to accept it as the answer

Answer (score 21):

The book ["Higher order Perl"](http://hop.perl.plover.com/) might be of interest for you. Best of all - it's free.

Comment: Very interesting, great tip, thanks and it's free (even better)

Comment: We get this for any new developers at work if they're not already familiar with it.

Comment: Wow, MJD finally got the text online!

Comment: +1 definitely, one of the best programming books I've read so far (still reading it)

Answer (score 21):

Well, first of all [Higher-Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/) is really good, but it's about functional programming, not objects.

[Perl Best Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596001738) is an excellent book, but it has limitations, and one of them is that Conway recommends using his own [Class::Std](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Class::Std) module to do inside-out objects, and the general consensus seems to be (1) that if you're going to do inside-out objects, [Object::InsideOut](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Object::InsideOut) and [Class::InsideOut](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Class::InsideOut) are better ways to do it (2) and anyway, using "Moose" based objects is a better way to go.

This illustrates what is probably *the* major difference between the Java and Perl world: There's rarely one standard way of doing anything with Perl.  Starting as someone who feels comfortable with objects in another language, I would guess that the most interesting thing about Conway's now slightly dated [Object Oriented Perl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1884777791) is watching him gradually develop different ways of adding OOP features you've been taking for granted.

I like the basic blessed-hash style of Perl OOP myself, but you need to understand that it's encapsulation is really weak, and that while method-inheritance works, there's typically no data-inheritance.  There are also some rather perlish tricks in wide use, such as automatically generating accessors using an `AUTOLOAD` routine.

As for what you can read on the subject, don't neglect the on-line documentation that comes with Perl: [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html).  Note the "Tutorials" section at the top.  If you're rusty on Perl's references and data structures, read the first two: [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).  A little down the list, you'll see multiple OOP tutorials.  These are largely about simple href-based objects, though there are some serious oddities in there, such as Tom Christiansen's scheme for closure-based objects down at the bottom of: [perldoc perltoot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html)

If you're interested in some of the newer ways people do things, you might want to start with [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Moose&mode=all) which is supposed to be the closest you can get to perl6 objects while still writing perl5 code.  By the way: ignore the word "postmodern" there, it's a silly joke that doesn't make any sense.

If you're interested in inside-out objects (which have bullet proof encapsulation, but are perhaps a little annoying to debug-- you can't just use [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data::Dumper) on the object to get it's status), I'd suggest starting with this [perl5 wiki page](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?inside_out_object).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for taking your time and giving this impressive write up!

Comment: Class::Std sucks badly, all it does is cause pain. That suggestion is probably the worst idea in PBP. I wonder if 'Std' is an acronym here ( http://www.cdc.gov/STD/ ). There is a lot of discussion of PBP suggestions to be found on Perlmonks and elsewhere.

Comment: I think you mean "hash-based" instead of "href-based"

Comment: Well no... really with a typical perl OOP approach you bless a hash-reference, which is often abbreviated as "href", and when speaking loosely, we sometimes just call this "hash-based".

Comment: @user256307 Not to be a stickler, but we bless a hash and bless just happens to take and return a reference to it.

Answer (score 8):

Check out:

- [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735) - nice collection of suggested best practices.  Even if you don't adopt them, the discussion of the reasoning behind the suggestions is valuable.
- [Perl Testing: A Developer's Notebook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100926) - Provides excellent coverage of Perl's testing capabilities.
- [Object Oriented Perl](http://www.manning.com/conway/) - An excellent book about how to use and abuse the Perl's object system.  This book is a bit dated.  It predates inside out objects (whose time has come and gone) and Moose, both important developments in OOP.  If you have a large body of older OO Perl to maintain, this book may well come in handy.
- [PerlMonks](http://perlmonks.org/) - A very handy Perl focused site with a very generous and collegial tone.  A good place to go for help and feedback.  Its been in operation for years, so there is also a massive archive of posts.

Comment: Testing (with Test::More, Test::Exception, Test::NoWarnings, etc) is pretty important, and Perl (well, CPAN) makes it easy. Of course you may be very familiar with all this depending on what you were doing/where you were working 8 years ago...
also you may be interested in Log4perl - especially if you've used Log4j in Java - which is probably the easiest to add logging

Comment: Good list - going through it - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use [Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/). Read about Moose and MooseX::Declare. Try [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/). Read [Perl Iron Man Planet](http://ironman.enlightenedperl.org/) aggregator.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [`Moose`](http://moose.perl.org) then that is the best way to go (IMHO).

There is a book available: [Moose. A postmodern object system for Perl 5](http://www.lulu.com/content/paperback-book/moose/7406976)

[image: Moose Book]

The book is the printed version of the excellent online [`Moose::Manual`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual.pod)

/I3az/

Comment: thanks, Moose seems to be a hot thing, darn the book is not free :)

Comment: @DroidIn.net:  Yep its damned hot!  Checkout out the Moose question/answers here on SO.  BTW... there is a free PDF: http://blog.urth.org/2009/02/moose-book-well-sort-of.html (see "PDF output..." link) and see the Github link in comments for creating your own.